# Using Common Table Expressions with EntityFramework 5

Tags: sql, entity-framework, common-table-expression

I am using EF5 Code First and I have a standard `Tree` type structure which is a bunch of nested `Folder`s.  Some folders have `Device`s inside them.  What I want to do is be able to select a folder and find all devices within that folder and its child folders.

After some digging it seems I need use Common Table Expressions in order to generate the data I need.  Unfortunately I am really struggling with how to do this.

```
public class Folder
{
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> PresentInFolders { get; set; }
 }
```

I have attempted to add a `GetDevicesForFolderRecursively` function based on the work on [this MSDN article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Recursive-or-hierarchical-bf43a96e).  The query is incomplete as `folder.FolderId equals device.FolderID` wont work in my situation because a device can be in more than one folder so it has a list of folders it's in.

```
public IQueryable<Device> GetDevicesForFolderRecursively(int folderID)
{
    return from folder in this.FlatFolders
            join device in this.Devices on folder.FolderId equals device.FolderID
            where folder.FolderId == folderID
            select device;
}
```

Once this is out the way, I also dont know how accurately construct the CTE.  The CTE that the MSDN article creates looks like so but I dont know how to modify it for my needs and how this would work recursively?

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ManagerEmployees]
AS
    WITH    cte ( ManagerEmployeeID, EmployeeID )
              AS ( SELECT   EmployeeID ,
                            EmployeeID
                   FROM     dbo.Employees
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   e.EmployeeID ,
                            cte.EmployeeID
                   FROM     cte
                            INNER JOIN dbo.Employees AS e ON e.ReportsToEmployeeID = cte.ManagerEmployeeID
                 )
    SELECT  ISNULL(EmployeeID, 0) AS ManagerEmployeeID ,
            ISNULL(ManagerEmployeeID, 0) AS EmployeeID
    FROM    cte");
```

**Update**

I have managed to get the CTE query to this state but still doesnt quite work.  It doesnt understand `AS ( SELECT   FolderId , [EstateManagerService].dbo.Devices.DeviceSerial` and im not sure what values are meant to be in there?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ManagerEmployees]
AS
WITH    cte ( FolderID, DeviceID )
          AS ( SELECT   FolderId ,
                        [EstateManagerService].dbo.Devices.DeviceSerial

               FROM     [EstateManagerService].dbo.Folders
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   e.Folder_FolderId,
                        cte.FolderID
               FROM     cte
                        INNER JOIN [EstateManagerService].dbo.FolderDevices AS e ON e.Folder_FolderId = cte.FolderID
             )
SELECT  ISNULL(DeviceID, 0) AS FolderID ,
        ISNULL(FolderID, 0) AS DeviceID
FROM    cte
```